# changing css to a path of a menu

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

I'm using jquery, superfish to create a dynamic menu.
But, I'm having trouble adding a bold class to the selected path.
I'm able to select the right submenu and extract the right parents. But when I want to apply the bold css property to the element and the parents. Every item turns bold.
When, I clearly see that some of the child elements don't have the bold css class.

```
$n = $("li[id=li_"+$num+"]").parents().filter("li").not('ul menu').addClass('bold');
```

Comment: What's your mark-up? Also the `'ul menu'` selector will look for a `<menu>` element within a `<ul>` element. And there's no such `menu` element. Did you mean `'ul .menu'` (or `'ul.menu'`)?

Comment: David, given `.not('ul menu')` I think you just found his bug.

Comment: @airnet: or perhaps `'ul, menu'`?

Comment: OK this is the thing. I understand what's going on. But not sure how to fix it.
Basically, I have 
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2
     <ul>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</li>

So, if I select node 4. I set it's css to bold and if i do it to the parent. It carries over to node 3.

Comment: Wow ok, thanks to the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The children are likely inheriting the bold from their bolded parents.  For instance, if you are using nested lists, the "bold" class on a parent `li`, coupled with a `font-weight:bold;` style on that class, will make everything in that `li` bold, including children without the bold class.  You will likely need css similar to the following:

```
li.bold li {
    font-weight:normal;
}
li.bold {
    font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

Also, "bold" is a bad name for this class - you want to describe the semantics, not the display.  I would use something like "selected", "highlighted" or "active".

[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ersUr/)

Comment: Thank you so much..it was inheritance from the parent. BUt yeah my selector was named differently. Just trying to explain the scenario